# Finding the intersection of two functions (graphs)

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I am trying to solve a problem with functions, but we haven't studied it in school, and I have some problems. I am trying to find the intersection of two functions:
$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+2}$ and $g(x)=x+1$. I am using GeoGebra, and this is what I have made:
[image]
So according to the answers, the only one intersection is for $x=-\frac{2}{3}$. How can I see that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Write the equation $\dfrac{x^2}{x+2} = x + 1$ and try to figure out for which values of $x$ the equality is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ intersect when their $y$-values are equal for a common value of $x$. So the $x$-coordinate of the point of intersection must satisfy the equation
$$f(x) = g(x)$$
Solving for $x$ tells you what value(s) $x$ must take for the graphs to intersect; then you can verify that they do by evaluating $f$ and $g$ and making sure you get the same value.

So in this case, you need to solve
$$\dfrac{x^2}{x+2} = x+1$$
Multiplying by through by $x+2$ and doing some algebra gives you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align} 
\frac{x^2}{x+2}=x+1 \quad \iff & x^2=(x+1)(x+2) \\
\iff & x^2=x^2+3x+2 \\
\iff &3x+2=0 \\ 
\iff &x=-\tfrac{2}{3}
\end{align}$$